# How to get the min effdate based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an effective dated table in an oracle database that shows employment history and there are multiple dates with the same position. I need to reduce this down to the start and end dates each time an employee was in the position. Employees can move in and out of the same position so I cannot use min(start_date) over (partition by ID) as this just gets me the first time they were in the position.
I need another condition, but I don't know what.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data and expected result. For the answers to make sense at laeast that is needed. Also, it would be usefull to see some of your attempts so far...

Comment: ... Database version is also significant. The match_recognize is a good answer for Oracle 12cR1 or later. Not for older versions...

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`match_recognize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html) to group intervals together conditionally.

Sample data:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> order by emp_id, job_id, dt_from
> ```
>
> ```
> EMP_ID | JOB_ID | DT_FROM    | DT_TO     
> -----: | -----: | :--------- | :---------
>      1 |      1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31
>      1 |      1 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-31
>      1 |      1 | 2020-03-20 | 2020-04-15
>      1 |      1 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-05-31
>      1 |      1 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-07-10
>      1 |      2 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-02-15
>      1 |      2 | 2020-02-16 | 2020-03-15
>      1 |      2 | 2020-03-16 | 2020-06-30
>      2 |      1 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-03-15
>      2 |      1 | 2020-03-16 | 2020-05-01
>      2 |      1 | 2020-05-10 | 2020-06-30
> ```

Query and result:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> match_recognize (
>   /*Restart grouping at each new employee and job*/
>   partition by emp_id, job_id
>   /*Order validity intetvals*/
>   order by dt_from, dt_to
>   measures
>     first(dt_from) as dt_from,
>     last(dt_to) as dt_to
>   /*Group adjacent intervals together*/
>   pattern (a overlap*)
>   define
>     /*Adjacency:
>       previous interval ends after the start of the current
>       or a day before current
>     */
>     overlap as dt_from <= prev(dt_to)+1
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> EMP_ID | JOB_ID | DT_FROM    | DT_TO     
> -----: | -----: | :--------- | :---------
>      1 |      1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-04-15
>      1 |      1 | 2020-05-12 | 2020-07-10
>      1 |      2 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-06-30
>      2 |      1 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-05-01
>      2 |      1 | 2020-05-10 | 2020-06-30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=674fd1a454dc917404116548eb2a3274)*